# Client Tools installation issues (OpenShift Online)

Tags: proxy, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I was trying to install the openshift client tools on my windows system . I have already installed ruby and git as the prerequisites for it. I also installed rhc package on my system using gem install rhc. However when i type rhc setup (to connect to OpenShift and sets up your keys and domain) i get the following error.

Unable to connect to the server (No connection could be made because the target
machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (https://openshift.redhat.com:443)).
Check that you have correctly specified your OpenShift server
'https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api'

I thought may be it is because i am on a corporate network and tried the following to set the proxy but it gives me invalid option.
C:>rhc setup  --http-proxy="http://username:password@proxy_ip:port"
invalid option: --http-proxy="http://username:password@proxy_ip:port"

Can anyone guide me on this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I even tried creating http_proxy as an environment variable with value as "username:passwd@proxyip:port"; but now i am getting "Server returned an unexpected error code: 407" as an error code. Somebody please help!!

Comment: I get this error while port forwarding on rhc. This is not a concrete solution but whenever I encounter this, I usually give it a 5-10 seconds breather and try again. Starts port forwarding again in max 2 attempts. It's a shared resource that we're trying to connect, so maybe that's why.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question but I had a similar error:

```
Unable to connect to the server (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, 
or not known (https://openshift.redhat.com:443)). Check that you have correctly
specified your OpenShift server 'https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains'.
```

I went to the openshift website and created my first application there using the same username/password/domain name. Then when I re-ran `rhc setup` it completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exception "407"

I set HTTP_PROXY env variable. I suspect that rhc does not read that env variable... Also I set http_proxy into .gemrc file but the error always occurs.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You should create a new seperate question or comment on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception, I was entering the email with which I registered: `myuser@gmail.com`, but I entered my email with domain OpenShift, I mean, I entered: `myuser@openshift.redhat.com` and this worked for me.